# Lebesgue measure of the elements that appears finitely in a countable infinite collection

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, problem-solving, self-learning

Let $\lambda^*$ and $\mathcal{L}(\Bbb{R})$ denote the Lebesgue measure and the Lebesgue sigma algebra on $\Bbb{R}$ respectively.

Let $\{A_k\}_{k \in \Bbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{L}(\Bbb{R})$ such that $[0,1] = \cup _{k\in \Bbb{N}}A_k$ and $\sum_{k\in \Bbb{N}}\lambda(A_k) < \infty$ . Then, the set $B$ of the elements which appears only
finitely on $\{A_k\}_{k \in \Bbb{N}}$ satisfies $\lambda^*(B)=1$ .

In order to prove it, I am trying to understand $B$, but I am getting stuck.
We can desbribe it as:

$$B=\{x \in [0,1] \, | \,  \exists n_0 \forall n \geq n_0 : x \notin A_n \}=\{x \in [0,1] \, | \,  \exists n_0 \forall n \geq n_0 : x \in A_n^c \}$$

Since, we can define the function $n_. : B \hookrightarrow \Bbb{N}, n_x = \min\{m \in \Bbb{N} \, | \, \forall n\geq m : x\in A_n^c\}$  which gives us an equivalence relation on $B$ : $x \sim y  \leftrightarrow n_x=n_y$, so we have the partition $\{B_n\}_{n\in \Bbb{N}}$ of $B$ where $B_n=\{x \in B : n=n_x \}$

I suspect that $\lambda^*(B_n) \geq 1/n$ or something similar but I am very stuck and don't no how to continue or if it is better trying to prove that $\lambda^*(B^c)=0$ , so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's possible to have any combination of $\lambda(B_n)$, subject to their sum being equal to $1$. For example, take $$a_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lambda(B_i)$$ and let $A_n=(a_n,1]$. So the solution isn't going to work by finding bounds on $\lambda(A_n)$ separately from each other.

Comment: @ZoeAllen Sorry, but I don't understand. In fact, why the sum of $\lambda(B_n)$ is 1 ? The $B_n$ are not Lebesgue measurable, so the countably additivity doesn't affect them.  Also, what that mean the sets $A_n$ ? I don't know if you refer to the sets $A_k$ of the hypothesis

Comment: I think the $B_n$ do turn out Lebesgue measurable. My comment isn't proving the sum. I'm giving possible $A_n$ as an example to show why your suggested method won't work. I'm refering to the same $A_n$.

Comment: @ZoeAllen Okay, now I understand, thanks. Do you know a way to prove it? By trying what I said, $\lambda^*(B^c)=0$, I also got stuck.

Comment: It seems pretty tricky. I think the way to do it might be to think of the set $C_n$​ of elements that appear at least $n$ times. If we say $s$ is the sum of the measures of the $A_n$​, then we should be able to show that the measure of $C_n$​ is less than or equal to $\frac{s}{n}$. Then $B^c$ is the intersection of all $C_n$​, so it has to be less than any positive number.

Comment: I think we can prove $C_n$​ is smaller than $\frac{s}{n}$ by defining $D_{mn}$​, the set of elements contained in at least $n$ of the first $m$ sets. We can quite easily prove that $D_{mn}$​ is smaller than $\frac{s}{n}$ for any $m$, and $C_n$​ is the union of $D_{mn}$​, so its measure is the limit of the measure of the $D_{mn}$​. So it's also bounded $\le\frac{s}{n}$.

Comment: @ZoeAllen I see, that seems to work, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Borel-Cantelli Lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma. I think the key step in making the proof truly "visible" is noticing that the set $B$ of elements that appear in infinitely many $A_k$ (in the language of probability theory, this is the [event]=[set of $x$] that infinitely many [events $A_k$ occur]=[sets $A_k$ contain $x$], i.e. the events $A_k$ occur infinitely often, which is often abbreviated "i.o." in probability contexts) is:
$$[A_k \text{ i.o.}] = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k.$$
Another way to think about it is
$$\textbf 1_{[A_k \text{ i.o.}]} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \textbf1_{A_n}$$
(indeed $[A_k \text{ i.o.}]$ is often written $[\limsup A_k]$). See the Wikipedia page for the full proof if you need extra help after this hint.

There is an alternative slick proof via Fubini's theorem [http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-BC.pdf](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-BC.pdf). That link has some interesting probability questions that can be solved using the Borel-Cantelli lemma. This pdf also has some https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2015/2dc1c9e37d402c000b628ee85e2228d1_MIT18_304S15_project2.pdf.

The above links also discuss that this result has a partial converse: if we assume a further condition on the $A_k$ (a probabilistic notion called "independence of events"), the converse is true. That is known as the 2nd Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: The set of elements that appear in infinitely many $A_k$ is $B^c$, not $B$, but this is great and it works, thank you so much!